# Java DriverManager does not load Mysql driver

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, driver

Java DriverManager does  not load Mysql driver

```
DriverManager
    static {
        loadInitialDrivers();
        println("JDBC DriverManager initialized");
    }
```

Mysql jdbc driver is under Tomcat library.

```
  tomcat/lib/mysql-jdbc.jar
```

From debugger,  Before calling DriverManager.getDriver(URL), a breakpoint is
set in the method loadInitialDrivers(), but execution is not stopped there. It is static method, when the class is loaded, and the static method is called?

The list of loaded drivers (`registeredDrivers`) is empty.

### UPDATE

Add ojdbc6.jar into tomcat/lib, and then restart tomcat. DriverManager did not
load the driver either. What might be the problem? It seems that tomcat is ignoring all JDBC jars under tomcat/lib directory.

Also tried: copy jdbc drivers to webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib, it did not help.

Comment: What is `mysql-jdbc.jar`? The name of the current MySQL JDBC driver is `mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar`. And `ojdbc6.jar` is nine years old.

Comment: It is mysql jdbc connector jar. It was working before.

Comment: using gradle to download jdbc jars. mysql --- group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
 oracle --- group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc6', version: '11.2.0.3'

Comment: If I use java only without tomcat, DriverManager can load the drivers successfully. I guess it might be classpath(class loader issue).

Comment: Is there a way to print out classpath for a webapp to see if the jdbc jars are in the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running SQL from a simple Java application is quite different from running SQL  from a JEE server such as Tomcat (well... half a JEE server at least).

Do not use `static` initializers. Instead, JEE (Java Enterprise Edition) does it differently, by a myriad of very good reasons:

- In Tomcat you don't need to "load" the driver. Just place it in `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` and restart Tomcat. That's it. The driver is already loaded. See the Tomcat log while it's starting and you'll see it. Tomcat (as any JEE server would do) takes care of loading it.
- Then , what you need to do is to create a JDBC Data Source. There are plenty of examples out there on how to do that. You do this by modifying the conf/server.xml file and restarting Tomcat. Make sure you give the data source a name you remember; you'll use it in the next step. Again look at Tomcat's log file while starting and you'll see you brand new data source being registered/created.
- Next, in your JEE code you retrieve the Data Source from the JNDI directory using the name you configured in the previous step, and use it to create a `Connection`. Again, plenty of examples out there on how to do this.
- Finally, with the `Connection` you can run all the SQL statements you want. This is the part you already know well. Do it the same way you normally do.

Comment: DriverManager can not be used in Tomcat environment?  It is standard java library. How is it disabled? thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can be used. It just doesn't make sense for enterprise-grade applications. You could need that to do something really special, like loading unknown drivers dynamically at runtime. But again, you don't really do that in enterprise applications.